# Methods for using the Golden Ratio in fluid application UI design?

Tags: design-principles, interface-design, composition

I have seen a bit about leveraging the Golden Ratio in traditional web design applications, however I've not found much in the way of thoughts on utilizing it within fluid desktop application design.  That is to say, when given an application that has potentially infinite possibilities in resize, how does one go about conceptually using the Golden Ratio in such scenarios?

Comment: Ratio is independent from resizing.

Comment: Square peg, round hole. In other words, you don't. The golden ratio isn't all that amazing of a tool anyways. Useful if you're building a roman temple, perhaps, but otherwise not as magical as some make it out to be.

Comment: Mostly mumbo-jumbo: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-often-is-the-golden-ratio-actually-used-in-modern-design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using percentage widths in your CSS can maintain column or element ratios:

`width: 61.8%;`

Just make sure you're aware of how CSS treats percentage widths and heights:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Comment: Well, was asking about application UI design vs web css based apps, but still relevant.  When I was thinking about this I was caught up in the moment and didn't consider just reverting to percentage amounts across the board.  Thanks, will play with that.