# Books on the Golden Ratio/Others for WebDesign?

Tags: page-layout, book

Is there any recommended books about using the Phi (Golden Ratio) for WebDesign?

I've seen a lot of layouts taking advantage of this proportion, but it would be great to read a book with a lot of examples and possible aplications of this math (and possible others) for WebDesign.

Thank you.

Comment: You can get a lot of good info on the golden ratio by reading the various questions and answers about it on these sites. There's some [good answers in the stackexchange cognitive science site](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/is-golden-ratios-association-with-perceived-beauty-a-myth), and I linked to some more good stuff on this site and the UI site in a comment on that question.

Comment: See also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-often-is-the-golden-ratio-actually-used-in-modern-design and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/why-does-the-golden-ratio-work-or-does-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**The Geometry of Design**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1616890363) is not about the web specifically but it is a great book on proportion systems in layout and product design in general.

For what it's worth, phi is not the end all proportion. There's a lot more value in considering standard view port sizes or the proportions of the screen. The beauty of phi has been most notably exploited in the classical book industry where you can change the proportions of the media to work with your design solution.*

[**Designing Books**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0907259235) has some excellent analysis on how to determine proportion systems based on the needs of the material. It's about printed books but there is much to learn about proportion and typography in all forms of design.

[**The Power of Limits**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590302591) is another excellent reference on the concept of proportion systems in general.

* [**The Form of the Book**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881791164) is a slim little gold mine on proportion and classical book layout.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much to it. Wikipedia sums it up well:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio

Keep in mind that in the context of graphic design, it's somewhat of an arbitrary building block. As such, it seems to be abused much more than used meaningfully.

Barring nothing else to go off of, staring with the golden ration isn't a bad thing. Just don't let it cloud other more tangible objectives.

Addendum:

In terms of web design, it's even less practical than the fixed canvas you get with architecture or print design.

The catch is that in web design, you less often have control over limiting vertical divisions. While you can provide a hard-stop for widths, you usually need to accomodate flexibility in vertical content/layout flows. As such, the golden ratio tends to fall a part a bit.

I'd suggest that if you have absolutely nothing to start from, while the golden ratio could work, for web design, there's probably better foundations to consider such as the many CSS grid systems out there.

Comment: You're completely right about the tangible objectives. But I could use it as a starting template for design proportions... Thank you.

Comment: That is true, though I still think there might be better options. I've updated my answer with some web-design centric thoughts.