# Can someone explain to me how to use golden ratio for layout purposes in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm willing to understand how to use golden ratio for layout purposes in Indesign. I've found a couple of 'explanations' over internet but they are too enigmatic and I can't really see the possible usage of it in Indesign projects. I know that other people are doing it so it's possible. Can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: Hi there! We have a question that incorporates more general uses of golden ratio in design. I think you  will find it quite interesting: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-often-is-the-golden-ratio-actually-used-in-modern-design I'm closing this question for now, if you have specific doubts about InDesign, you can edit and flag so a mod can re-open it (or you can open a new one!).

Comment: Always worth mentioning as well: The 'golden ratio' is more of an old wive's tale than it is a magic solution to layout. You can use it, of course, but there's isn't anything magical about it.